# An Exception Occurred In Driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation Now In Progress

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm using MySQL AWS RDS instance with my symfony. On some calls (they are not always the same), the period is not regular, I have an error:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Operation now in progress.
```

I looked for this error but it often indicates a connection problem. I'm sure the connection is ok from the client because we have thousands of calls like that every day but for few calls it shows this error.

Have you had this problem or have any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: We do have the same issue here, AWS RDS MariaDB & Symfony 4.4. Indeed only some calls are failling, usually on the CONNECT instruction. This started 5 days ago for us.
Maybe you can add the tag for ASW RDS and Symfony ?

Comment: check for 2002 error if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55954393/aws-rds-and-pdo-dont-work-sqlstatehy000-2002

Comment: This is not helping, this is not the same issue. Here, we do have some connectivity, only some requests are failing. And 2002 is regrouping many connectivity issues unfortunatly

Comment: @MinDBreaK did you find a solution to this problem? We are having the same issue currently

Comment: @ocind Unfortunatly no. The Issue come and go sometimes. We have some peak, and then it disappear for a month or two.

Comment: @MinDBreaK I see... regardless thanks for the info!

Comment: I know that I've come late to the party, but I've had an interesting observation.
On my server, I could only connect using the `root` MySQL user in combination with `sudo` (e.g. `sudo MySQL -u root -p`). 
I created a new MySQL user called `admin` which has all privileges, and I could connect using these credentials without having to use `sudo`, then I used the same MySQL user in my application and everything worked normally.
Note: you may want to create a user that interacts with the DB specific to your application instead of having a global one like I did because it's wrong.